# Posicionamiento flexbox

Tags: html, css

estoy teniendo un problema que no logro entender el por que sucede,

La cuestion es la siguiente: Hice una estructura HTML, la cual es la siguiente:

```
<section class="flex">
<article class="left">
        <h1 class="left-title">
            10,000+ of our users love our products.
        </h1>
        <h2 class="left-subtitle">
            We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service.
            See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.
        </h2>
    </div>
</article>

<article class="right">
    <div class="right-card">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-card">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-card">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
    </div>
</article>

<article class="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-card">
        <h2 class="bottom-card-name"> Colton Smith</h2>
        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
    <p class="bottom-card-text">
        "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
        Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
        Excellent!"
    </p>
    <div class="bottom-card">
        <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Irene Roberts</h2>
        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
    <p class="bottom-card-text">
        "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
        delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
    </p>
    <div class="bottom-card">
        <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Anne Wallace</h2>
        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
    <p class="bottom-card-text">
        "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
        standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"
    </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Codigo SASS:

```
:root{
--very-dark-magenta: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
--soft-pink: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
--dark-grayish-magenta: hsl(303, 10%, 53%);
--light-grayish-magenta: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
--white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

body{
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--white);
    background-image:url('../images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right 50vw bottom 70vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 5%;
}

.left{
    width: 27vw;
    &-title{
        font-size:3.8rem;
        font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
        color:var(--very-dark-magenta)
    }
    &-subtitle{
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
        color:var(--dark-grayish-magenta)
    }

    
}

.right{
    width: 450px;
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    &-card{
        padding-top: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;

        &-text{
            margin-left: 70px;
        }
       
        &:nth-child(2){
            margin-left: 50px;

        }
        &:nth-child(3){
            margin-left: 100px;
        }
        & img {
            width: 15px;
            flex-direction: inherit;
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo que hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, al darle a la clase `.flex` el valor de:

```
display:flex;
```

Todo se me posiciono de forma lateral, de esta forma:

(Como la herramienta de recortes de windows me dejo de funcionar, y al sacar pantallazo se ve todo mal, preferi subirlo a github, pueden verlo haciendo click [aca](https://eliiansito01.github.io/social-proof-section/)

Lo que yo necesito realizar es que, la parte de las estrellas quede en el lado derecho de la pagina, y, la parte que esta dentro del div "bottom", quede del lado de abajo de la pagina, pero no entiendo porque flexbox me lo posiciona asi.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que hicieras un bosquejo aunque sea en imagen de como quieres que queden distribuidos los elementos, por que la redacción al menos a mi no me lo deja claro

Comment: Claro, ahora subo la imagen que brinda la pagina que da el reto para hacer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Además de corregir elementos **div** faltantes, creo mejor sería suprimir la clase **flex** de la etiqueta *section* y disponer mejor los dos artículos *#left* y *#right* en el interior de un *div* con clase *.flex*
Esto vendría a ser más o menos:

```css
:root {
  --very-dark-magenta: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  --soft-pink: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
  --dark-grayish-magenta: hsl(303, 10%, 53%);
  --light-grayish-magenta: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
  --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--white);
  background-image: url("../images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 50vw bottom 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 5%;
}

.left {
  width: auto;
}
.left-title {
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
  color: var(--very-dark-magenta);
}
.left-subtitle {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
  color: var(--dark-grayish-magenta);
}

.right {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.right-card {
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #f7f2f7;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.right-card-text {
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.right-card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.right-card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.right-card img {
  width: 15px;
  flex-direction: inherit;
}
.bottom{
    display:flex;
}
.bottom-card {
    padding-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: indigo;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
.bottom-card-name {
}
.bottom-card-verify {
  color:violet;
}
.bottom-card-text {
  padding: 10px;
}
.bottom-card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.bottom-card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.bottom-card img {
  width: 15px;
  flex-direction: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
                <div class="flex">
                    <article class="left">
                            <h1 class="left-title">
                                10,000+ of our users love our products.
                            </h1>
                            <h2 class="left-subtitle">
                                We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service.
                                See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.
                            </h2>
                    </article>

                    <article class="right">
                        <div class="right-card">
                            <div class="stars"></div>
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-card">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-card">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <article class="bottom">
                    <div class="bottom-card">
                        <h2 class="bottom-card-name"> Colton Smith</h2>
                        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
                    <p class="bottom-card-text">
                        "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
                        Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
                        Excellent!"
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-card">
                        <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Irene Roberts</h2>
                        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
                    <p class="bottom-card-text">
                        "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
                        delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-card">
                        <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Anne Wallace</h2>
                        <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
                    <p class="bottom-card-text">
                        "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
                        standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
```

He incluido las clases *.bottom* faltantes y alguna pequeña modificación más...

Comment: Esta respuesta es buena +1, tal vez si expande un poco mas en la explicación sería aún mejor

Answer (score 4):

Revisando tu código, **considero** que los problemas se te están presentando principalmente por una estructura HTML un tanto compleja y no bien aplicada para el resultado que buscas.

Comentarios:

- Si tienes una sección de *testimonios* ¿por qué no cada uno de estos ser un `article`?
- Estos N testimonios tenerlos tal vez dentro de un `section`
- Ahora si el `section` que contiene a los testimoniales aplicarle *flexbox*

Similar a lo anterior, ahora se podría pensar en lo mismo pero para la sección de *stars* y *títulos*

- Ambos títulos (*el `h1` y el `h2`*) pueden quedar dentro de otro `article`
- Las calificaciones de estrellas están dentro de un `div` cada una de ellas (*y al menos desde mi pobre conocimiento*) eso así lo dejaría es decir no requeriría mayor trabajo ahi

  - Esto lo comento por que tanto los [`span` como así los `img` son elementos en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea) y aparecerían en fila (*lo cual hasta cierto punto debe ahorrar trabajo*)
- Ahora si el `section` que contiene a los títulos y las calificaciones aplicarle *flexbox*

Además:

- Por cierto si notas, justo después de la etiqueta de cierre del `h2` tienes un `div` que cierra pero este no aparece aperturado mas arriba en sitio alguno
- No logro identificar la funcionalidad del div con la clase `stars`, entonces **me atrevería** a pensar en removerlo del código

Entonces a nivel de HTML pudiera tener una estructura inicial y simplificada de esta forma:

```html
    <style>
      .titulos,
      .testimonios {
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>
    <section>
        <section class="titulos">
            <article >
                <h1>
                    10,000+ of our users love our products.
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service.
                    See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.
                </h2>
            </article>
    
            <article>
                <div>
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <span>Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <span>Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <span>Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="testimonios">
            <article>
                <h2> Colton Smith</h2>
                <h3>Verified Buyer</h3>
                <p>
                    "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
                    Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
                    Excellent!"
                </p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Irene Roberts</h2>
                <h3>Verified Buyer</h3>
                <p>
                    "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
                    delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
                </p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Anne Wallace</h2>
                <h3>Verified Buyer</h3>
                <p>
                    "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
                    standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Lo que presento aquí es una estructura básica(**faltan trabajar todos los demás estilos**) la cual considero una forma simple de estructurar la información en HTML y poder después mediante CSS distribuirlos de la manera deseada.

Recomiendo [cheques este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_lista_elementos#secciones)

*Importante, esto es solo una **aproximación** y ayudaría mucho considerar los aportes de otros usuarios*

Comment: Gracias BetaM, pero realizando esto, voy a poder dejar las cards debajo y el titulo, subtitulo y puntuacion arriba, tal y como muestra la imagen? Ya que mi problema era que no sabia como dejar abajo las cards, gracias

Comment: Prueba el código, responde a esa necesidad

Comment: Si, efectivamente queda en la parte de abajo, pero todavia desconozco como puedo hacer para llevar lo que viene a ser la parte de las estrellas al lado derecho de la pagina, no se si usando "Margin-right" sea la forma apropiada

Answer (score 3):

Por defecto, la propiedad flex-direction está en row. A menos de que la modifiques, los elementos se colocaran uno al lado del otro. Si quieres que flexbox te coloque los elementos uno abajo del otro, debes añadir la clase `flex-direction: column` tal que cambie su dirección por defecto.

### Solución

Utilizando tus clases, solamente deberías agregar un par como estas:

```css
   
 .flex {
    display: flex;
  }
      
 .flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
 .justify-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
/** Estas la debes modificar tal que te quede así **/

 .section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 5%;
 }
 .right {
    width: 450px;
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
```

Y luego tu HTML debes variarlo un poco tal que:

```html
<section class="flex flex-col section">
      <div class="flex justify-between">
        <article class="left">
          <h1 class="left-title">10,000+ of our users love our products.</h1>
          <h2 class="left-subtitle">
            We only provide great products combined with excellent customer
            service. See what our satisfied customers are saying about our
            services.
          </h2>
        </article>
        <article class="right">
          <div class="right-card">
            <div class="stars"></div>
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
          </div>
          <div class="right-card">
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
          </div>
          <div class="right-card">
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" srcset="" />
            <span class="right-card-text">Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

      <article class="bottom">
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="bottom-card">
            <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Colton Smith</h2>
            <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
            <p class="bottom-card-text">
              "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a
              week prior. Not only did they find the original order, but we also
              received it in time. Excellent!"
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="bottom-card">
            <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Irene Roberts</h2>
            <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
            <p class="bottom-card-text">
              "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around.
              Completely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the
              speed of delivery."
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="bottom-card">
            <h2 class="bottom-card-name">Anne Wallace</h2>
            <h3 class="bottom-card-verify">Verified Buyer</h3>
            <p class="bottom-card-text">
              "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the
              very high standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend
              them to everyone!"
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando agregas la propiedad `display` con valor `flex` a un elemento **(contenedor rojo)**, hay un estilo en concreto que se aplica por defecto y *en segundo plano* a este mismo elemento. Es el siguiente:

```css
flex-direction: row
```

- `flex-direction: row` hace que todo *hijo* **(contenedores verdes)** del elemento *padre* **(cuadrado rojo)** con `display: flex` se vea en fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es así porque así funciona `flexbox`, que es el motor de todo esto.

Así de sencillo.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo buenas noches apenas estoy aprendiendo de Html y CSS, creo que el problema es que tu etiqueta ¨Section¨ no esta cerrada, y por eso cuando le aplicas el Flex a la etiqueta section, como es la etiqueta padre se la estas aplicando a todos los elementos. Cierrala antes de empezar la seccion de abajo, aplicale un space between para separarlas y eso creo que te ayudara